# How to Insert a List to a Column in a Csv File

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file ('test.csv') which looks like this:
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4

For each name, I have a list of numbers (for the discussion, let's say 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40).

I want to insert each list of numbers to each name, which would look like this:

```
Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4
1,11,21,31

2,12,22,32

3,13,23,33

4,14,24,34

5,15,25,35

6...

7

8

9

10,20,30,40
```

So far, as you would see in the code below, all I managed is to insert the names header.

How can I insert the data, without overwriting the header row.

Thanks!

```
with open('test.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    filewriter.writerow(['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4'])

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
```

Comment: sorry, the 1, 11, 21, 31 should be one line below.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you want from the format of this, however, can you write to a new file? (The delete the old one and rename the new one, if you need to replace what's on disk)?

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question to fix this

Comment: @doctorlove I edit the question, hope it's more clear. It is possible to write a new file, not sure how

Answer (score 0):

Explode CSV with new line("\n") character after that start parsing with second "1" not "0". Explode again with comma(",").

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm
you can check it here. 
ex: numbers = filewriter.split("\n")   and than inside loop  number = numbers[i].split(",")